# Task execution in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am new to Microsoft azure. Is azure function  app sufficient to write application logic for Desktop appllication and IOT devices or is there any other way to write logic and perform task execution in azure.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a little, are you asking if you can use Azure Function to write application logic for application running on IoT Device?  If your IoT device is running [Azure IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/), you can use [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-function) within your module.  Otherwise, you can use [Azure IoT Device SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks).

Comment: Can Azure Function be used to write all application logic for application running on IoT Device.